# Exchange: find where is stored an email by its internalMessagedId

Tags: exchange-2013

I have some trouble with Exchange, I received some emails from a gmail account and I didn't find them in my mailbox.
I check Echange logs with Get-MessageTrackingLog and I could find this events:

```
HAREDIRECTFAIL
RECEIVE
AGENTINFO
SEND
DELIVER
DELIVER
```

Also my antispam software has that message flagged as delivered.
However i did not find them in my mailbox! I tried by webmail, by outlook, in junks, deleted messages but I did not find anything. My delivery queue is empty.

Is there any command to find where a particular message is stored (mailbox and folder) by its messageid or by internalmessagedid?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any powershell cmdlet for Exchange that will let you find this information outright.  You could do something like:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "yourmail" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery “Body:’*xx-xx-xx*’” -TargetMailbox administrator -TargetFolder Export
```

But that's really no different than pulling up Outlook and using the search function there.

If you have an HA setup for Exchange, dig in to why you are receiving the `HAREDIRECTFAIL` issues.  If not, you can probably ignore the error.

Also check your Conflicts folder and Sync Issues folders in Outlook (you'll need to be in Folder View).

Comment: I found 2700 Sync Conflicts!!!! But I can not find any useful details.

Comment: I'm rebuilding the Outlook profile, however I can not find these email also in webmail, so I think this is not connected to outlook sync problem.

Comment: It could still get moved in OWA if a conflict happens after Outlook tries to sync.  Have you tried to the Advanced Find/search in Outlook?  If you are willing to update your OP with the full tracking log output of that message I might be able to see what is going on, but if it says "Deliver" to your mailbox, then it should be there.  Also check your "Recover Deleted Items" to make sure it didn't somehow get thrown into the Dumpster right away as well.